# .htaccess rewrite when form submission

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Let's say I have a website where the main page (index.php) of this website has a simple form. It's a text box where you enter a country, and submit it. It submits to results.php by GET. This page, given that the country exists, outputs a list of elements associated with that country.

So you go to example.com, you enter "Argentina" into the form and submit it. The browser makes a request to `example.com/result.php?country=Argentina`, and there you see the results.

But I would like to do this by routing/rewriting. So instead of the page listing the elements for Argentina being located at the URL `example.com/result.php?country=Argentina` (Long And Ugly), I want it to be located at `example.com/Argentina` (Short And Sweet).

One way of half way achieving this is through rewriting in the .htaccess like this:

`RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ result.php?country=$1 [NC]`

Now I can go to the SAS URL and see the same page as if I went to the LAU URL. Great for linking and SEO. But as index.php submits a form to result.php, if I actually do the search for Argentina from the main page, I will still be taken to the LAU URL, and not the SAS URL.

I know one way to get around this is to instead make a rewrite rule that takes the LAU URL and redirects to the corresponding SAS URL, and also have a rule sending all SAS URLs to result.php, and let result.php handle the parameters by exploding `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']`. But somehow, this doesn't seem very clean. Is there a better way, that ensures I will also see the SAS URL when submitting the form?

Comment: I think you ca do it with jquery, changing the "action" of the form berore to send it.

Comment: @NicholasNur No need for jquery, plain JS will suffice. And changing the form action last second won't do any good, but I can catch the form submission and instead of sending the form I could change the window location to 'example.com/' + searchbox.value. Still I would need the redirect mentioned for those who have JS deactivated. So I was thinking there might be some non-JS solution for this.